# app engine java: debugging servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

This may be a basic question but I am using app engine in eclipse
to develop a servlet and would like to debug my application as there
is a line of code which is tripping my application somewhere and causing
it to output nothing but a server error. I have tried debugging by right
clicking and selecting Debug As -> Web Application and opening a browser
to http://localhost:8888/ and selecting my servlet but when I do this I
do not see eclipse indigo classic step through the servlet's lines of
code. And I don't know where to find a log file with the offending output.
Any tips on how to proceed with the app engine servlet debug process would
be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application needs some configuration if you want to be able to run it locally. Open `Properties > Deployment assembly` of your project, and specify how its structure maps to the web app structure. Then starting a local tomcat in debug mode (with the app deployed there) should work fine (unless you use the Datastore)

Comment: Yes I use the datastore for persistence. Also I'm not sure why I would need to use Tomcat since I think there is already a servlet container called Jetty which is run by default. I do not see a File -> Properties -> Deployment assembly entry.

Comment: what plugins do you have? I don't have a jetty by default.